# Popunder / Tabunder script not working on mobile or set only for desktop

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    window.location.href = "https://google.com/";
}
}
```

How can I get this script to work on desktop only?

Or get it to work on mobile devices.

The script reloads the current tab to google and opens another tab with the test link.
Test link

I hope some one can help me with this. Preferrably without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly mean

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].onclick=function() {
      window.open("https://google.com/","blank");
    } 
  }
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].onclick=function() {
      window.open(this.href,"_blank");
      location="https://google.com/";
    } 
  }
}
```